# Unable to login using bcrypt, bcrypt compare always returns false

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, bcrypt

Register works fine;

When login I always get back error message : `Invalid login credentials`.
As you see in my code I should get this message if bcrypt compare returns false

I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong,

**Login ctrl**

```
User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
      }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occurred',
            error: err
          });
        }
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            title: 'Login failed',
            error: {
              message: 'Invalid login credentials'
            }
          });
        }

        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            title: 'Login failed',
            error: {
              message: 'Invalid login credentials'
            }
          });
        }
        var token = jwt.sign({
          user: user
        }, 'secret', {
          expiresIn: 7200
        });
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Successfully logged in',
          token: token,
          userId: user._id
        });
      })

    },
```

**Register Ctrl**

```
signup: function (req, res) {

        console.log(req.body)

        var user = new User({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
            email: req.body.email
        });

        user.save(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'User created',
                obj: result
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: what json resp do you get back?

Comment: Do a `console.log(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10))` on your log in function and see if you're getting a match with what's saved in the db. That should help you at least narrow it down.

Comment: console.log(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)) tried this  the hash dont match

Comment: _Register works fine_ I would at least doubt that, seeing that the saved password doesn't match later on

Comment: yes thats the issue, i am using the same password but get two different hash

Comment: Then by definition the passwords are different.  Make sure the password in req.body actually is the same as in hashed in the database (including white space, etc)

Comment: Is there any other password encrption module

Comment: both are same including white space, i checked them